# TrackballControls rotate by Z axis only

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'd like to modify the TrackballControls so that the camera only rotates on the Z-axis. However, I'm having a devil of a time understanding how the mouse/touch coordinates are mapped. The function below receives the mouse/touch x/y coordinates and a "projection" vector, which I assume is a projection of where the camera is expected to rotate, but that's not particularly clear to me either.

Basically I need to know what to do in the if statement below where it says "what goes here?" I need to essentially clip the vector so that rotation only happens on the Z axis. I know I could do this with a simple rotate, but I'd like to implement it in the TrackballControls so I can switch to "roll only" mode at will (camera only "rolls" on the Z axis). Can someone who is better at vector math give me a hand?

```
this.getMouseProjectionOnBall = (function(){

        var objectUp = new THREE.Vector3(),
            mouseOnBall = new THREE.Vector3();


        return function ( pageX, pageY, projection ) {

            mouseOnBall.set(
                ( pageX - _this.screen.width * 0.5 - _this.screen.left ) / (_this.screen.width*.5),
                ( _this.screen.height * 0.5 + _this.screen.top - pageY ) / (_this.screen.height*.5),
                0.0
            );

            var length = mouseOnBall.length();

            if ( _this.noRoll ) {

                if ( length < Math.SQRT1_2 ) {

                    mouseOnBall.z = Math.sqrt( 1.0 - length*length );

                } else {

                    mouseOnBall.z = .5 / length;

                }

            } else if (_this.rollOnly === true) {

                // What goes here?

            } else if ( length > 1.0 ) {

                mouseOnBall.normalize();

            } else {

                mouseOnBall.z = Math.sqrt( 1.0 - length * length );

            }

            _eye.copy( _this.object.position ).sub( _this.target );

            projection.copy( _this.object.up ).setLength( mouseOnBall.y )
            projection.add( objectUp.copy( _this.object.up ).cross( _eye ).setLength( mouseOnBall.x ) );
            projection.add( _eye.setLength( mouseOnBall.z ) );

            return projection;
        }

    }());
```

The actual camera rotation is done in the function below every frame. This function is much more understandable to me. Just basic angles and quaternion stuff. It's the above function that boggles my mind.

```
this.rotateCamera = (function(){

    var axis = new THREE.Vector3(),
        quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();


    return function () {
        var angle = Math.acos( _rotateStart.dot( _rotateEnd ) / _rotateStart.length() / _rotateEnd.length() );

        if ( angle ) {
            axis.crossVectors( _rotateStart, _rotateEnd ).normalize();

            angle *= _this.rotateSpeed;

            quaternion.setFromAxisAngle( axis, -angle );

            _eye.applyQuaternion( quaternion );
            _this.object.up.applyQuaternion( quaternion );

            _rotateEnd.applyQuaternion( quaternion );

            if ( _this.staticMoving ) {

                _rotateStart.copy( _rotateEnd );

            } else {

                quaternion.setFromAxisAngle( axis, angle * ( _this.dynamicDampingFactor - 1.0 ) );
                _rotateStart.applyQuaternion( quaternion );
            }

        }
    }

}());
```

Comment: Man, I really hope someone documents or at least comments this code. It's a headache for all of us that use three.js .

Comment: LOL, glad to hear I'm not the only one who can't figure it out.

Comment: have you had any success ?